# Creating Textfields by loop

Tags: java, for-loop, jtextfield

I have the following list of items in `volstextfield` which I then pass onto `createGUI`. I want to create a list of `JTextFields` with the names `vol1HH1,vol1HH2`. I get an error `Incompatible types: JTextField cannot be converted to volstextfield`, please can someone help?

```
public enum volstextfield {
    vol1HH1, vol1HH2
}

public void createGUI() {
    for (volstextfield direction : EnumSet.allOf(volstextfield.class)) {
        System.out.println(direction);
        direction = new JTextField(5); //i get an error here incompatible types: JTextField cannot be converted to volstextfield
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direction variable is of `enum` type. You cannot assign `JTextField` to `enum`. Try like

```
JTextField textfield = new JTextField(direction.getName());
```

Or use

```
JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
textfield.setName(direction.getName());
```

Comment: .getName() does not seem to work I get the error cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getname()
  location: variable direction of type volstextfield

Comment: You neeb bit modification in you enum too, try define like vol1hh1("vol1hh1") and add name variable to enum and add toString  to return the name. It will work.

Comment: i did with .name, i am now looking at your suggestion of defining the name to vol1hh1("vol1hh1")

Comment: I am not clear as to why defining the names like that would be different? or how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Enum is a *type* itself, the closest thing you could do is :

```
 // The Amount of JTextField is enum' length 
  JTextField direction[] = new JTextField[volstextfield .values().length]; 
        int i=0;

        for ( volstextfield v :volstextfield.values()) {
            direction [i++] = new JTextField(v.name());
        }
```